# C++ console application always on top?

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, always-on-top

I am **NOT** looking for:

- making *another* window always on top
- making any sort of GUI - [dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593403/always-in-front-dialogs) etc... on top

I am however looking for a way how to make my simple C++ **console** application to stay always on top,

just to be clear - I am looking for a way how to do this programaticly :) I tried hard searching but only found the above - what I do not want...

So is there a way how to make your **console** app always on top programaticly in C++ on **Windows**?

PS: Yes there is an existing [question with a coresponding title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212527/keep-a-running-c-program-console-on-top)  but the OP of that question is actually looking for something else (keyboard hooks,...) - so answers there are off-topic to my question.

## Solution:

**Quick answer** => see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068650/c-console-application-always-on-top/27068814#27068814) by @AlexanderVX

**Example & explanation** =>  [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068650/c-console-application-always-on-top/27076663#27076663) below

Comment: If that is for Windows I can tell what you need. Is it?

Comment: This is quite likely to be window-framework-specific. Can you clarify what you're targetting? Windows, X Window, ...?

Comment: @Nit and others - **what is unclear?** (As this is much weirder coming after I've add that the purpose is for windows...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The link in OP post refers to Windows.

First you need to obtain a handle for your console window:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/124103

Or even better and modern: [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) way to get that console handle.

Then you need to do quite a simple trick:

```
::SetWindowPos(hwndMyWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
::ShowWindow(hwndMyWnd, SW_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Your link describes an overly complicated method of getting the handle for pre-XP versions of Windows. In XP and onward, you can just use `GetConsoleWindow()`.

Comment: Agree that GetConsoleWindow improves it.

Answer (score 5):

As [@AlexanderVX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068650/c-console-application-always-on-top/27068814#27068814) shows an quick answer, I wanted to also show you my final implementation with appropriate comments explaining what does what :) :

Don't forget to set Windows version same or greater than `0x0500` and include `windows.h` library:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
```

I've put **mini-app example** on: http://ideone.com/CeLQj3

Example with explanation:

```
// GetConsoleWindow() => returns:
// "handle to the window used by the console
// associated with the calling process
// or NULL
// if there is no such associated console."
HWND consoleWindowHandle = GetConsoleWindow();

if( consoleWindowHandle ){
    cout << endl << "Setting up associated console window ON TOP !";
    SetWindowPos(
        consoleWindowHandle, // window handle
        HWND_TOPMOST, // "handle to the window to precede
                      // the positioned window in the Z order
                      // OR one of the following:"
                      // HWND_BOTTOM or HWND_NOTOPMOST or HWND_TOP or HWND_TOPMOST
        0, 0, // X, Y position of the window (in client coordinates)
        0, 0, // cx, cy => width & height of the window in pixels
        SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW // The window sizing and positioning flags.
    );
    // OPTIONAL ! - SET WINDOW'S "SHOW STATE"
    ShowWindow(
        consoleWindowHandle, // window handle
        SW_NORMAL // how the window is to be shown
                  // SW_NORMAL => "Activates and displays a window.
                  // If the window is minimized or maximized,
                  // the system restores it to its original size and position.
                  // An application should specify this flag
                  // when displaying the window for the first time."
    );
    cout << endl << "Done.";
} else {
    cout << endl << "There is no console window associated with this app :(";
}
```

**References:**

- GetConsoleWindow =>
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- SetWindowPos =>
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx
- ShowWindow =>
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
- Setting WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT =>
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx#setting_winver_or__win32_winnt

*PS: I wanted to post this as an edit to @AlexanderVX's answer, but most of stackoverflow's reviewers somehow thought that "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post"...*